# MySQL Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I get this error

> "Every derived table must have its own alias"

When I run this query

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, artistId
FROM  artist
WHERE artistId=(
    SELECT artistId
    FROM roles
    WHERE movieCode ='$movie[movieCode]' and  role = 'Director'
) a
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. it' a purely mysql error.

Comment: T think this is related to PHP. Its. just that the OP don't include the php code he/she used. Please take note the syntax of the `$movie[movieCode]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row1=mysqli_query($conn,"
SELECT firstname, lastname, artistId 
FROM  artist WHERE 
artistId=(SELECT artistId FROM roles WHERE movieCode ='$movie[movieCode]' and  role = 'Director') AS table_alias ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

This should work, every subquery must have an alias "AS".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, artistId FROM artist WHERE artistId=
  (
    SELECT artistId FROM roles WHERE movieCode ='$movie[movieCode]' AND role = 'Director' AS directorTable
  )
```

Every table must be named.  When you create a new table with your second SELECT statement (because that is what you are doing), you need to name it with an AS clause.