# Setting alias for each derived table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alias

Since I got the same error type explained in some many other [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias):

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Every derived table must have its own alias

After carefully reading it including **every single duplicate question** (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568030/mysql-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias) for example), I have tried to assign for every derived table a specific alias.

This is my example query:

```
SELECT pl.*, p.cat_1, pb.id 
FROM table_1 AS pl
JOIN table_2 AS p ON p.id=pl.column_id 
JOIN table_3 AS pb ON pb.id=p.id
JOIN table_4 AS u ON u.id=pl.user_id
WHERE pl.value_1=2 AND pl.value_2 > 0 
ORDER BY id desc
```

Probably I'm doing something wrong, maybe this is not the best way to write the query? I don't know but without any suggestions I can not understand which is the problem, also because **the query in concrete works well** if it's executed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove AS in the alias also use alias in order by clause

Comment: ORDER BY id desc   use alias table name for id example like  ORDER BY pb.id desc

Comment: Your query has no derived table.  Hence, that query would not generate that error.

Comment: This sounds really strange. Maybe the problem is that I'm trying to execute this query via Knime mysql node?

Comment: @UgoL . . . That could be causing a problem.  I would suggest starting by running the query directly against the database.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, finally I have realized that the problem does not exist. The query executed using MySQL WorkBench works like a charm without the alias console message. Probably the Mysql node in Knime is affected by this warning since it works differently, it uses `jdbc.exceptions` in java. I think we can close this question, do you know how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: @UgoL . . . As the author of the question, you should be able to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query,

```
SELECT pl.*, p.cat_1, pb.id 
FROM table_1  pl
JOIN table_2  p ON p.id=pl.column_id 
JOIN table_3  pb ON pb.id=p.id
JOIN table_4  u ON u.id=pl.user_id
WHERE pl.value_1=2 AND pl.value_2 > 0 
ORDER BY pb.id desc
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim, unfortunately this is not the solution. I have already tried to execute again the query without the AS for each alias, but the problem still remains.